# How to do request spec for JWT authenticate app using RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a Rails 5 API only app and using knock to do JWT authenticate.

After complete the model and model spec, I start to do the request spec.

But I have no idea how to complete the authentication inside the request spec in the right way,

My users controller,

```
module V1
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user, except: [:create]
  end
end
```

Application controller,

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include Knock::Authenticable
  include ActionController::Serialization
end
```

My stupidest solution (call the get token request to get the JWT before the rest request),

```
context 'when the request contains an authentication header' do
  it 'should return the user info' do
    user  = create(:user)
    post '/user_token', params: {"auth": {"email": user.email, "password": user.password }}
    body = response.body
    puts body # {"jwt":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0ODgxMDgxMDYsInN1YiI6MX0.GDBHPzbivclJfwSTswXhDkV0TCFCybJFDrjBnLIfN3Q"}
    # use the retrieved JWT for future requests
  end
end
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
  def authenticated_header(user)
    token = Knock::AuthToken.new(payload: { sub: user.id }).token
    { 'Authorization': "Bearer #{token}" }
  end

  describe 'GET /users?me=true' do
    URL = '/v1/users?me=true'
    AUTH_URL = '/user_token'

    context 'when the request with NO authentication header' do
      it 'should return unauth for retrieve current user info before login' do
        get URL
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:unauthorized)
      end
    end

    context 'when the request contains an authentication header' do
      it 'should return the user info' do
        user  = create(:user)

        get URL, headers: authenticated_header(user)
        puts response.body
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: This mostly worked for me.  I posted my modifications in an extended answer.  Thanks Xinyang Li.  This was very helpful!

Comment: I did this but I got this error 

Failure/Error: token = Knock::AuthToken.new(payload: { sub: user.id }).token
     
     NoMethodError: undefined method `sign' for #<String:

Any idea? I'm using RoR 5.2

Answer (score 5):

With the help of Lorem's answer, I was able to implement something similar for my request spec. Sharing it here for others to see an alternate implementation.

```
# spec/requests/locations_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Locations API' do
  let!(:user) { create(:user) }
  let!(:locations) { create_list(:location, 10, user_id: user.id) }

  describe 'GET /locations' do
    it 'reponds with invalid request without JWT' do
      get '/locations'
      expect(response).to have_http_status(401)
      expect(response.body).to match(/Invalid Request/)
    end

    it 'responds with JSON with JWT' do
      jwt = confirm_and_login_user(user)
      get '/locations', headers: { "Authorization" => "Bearer #{jwt}" }
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
      expect(json.size).to eq(10)
    end
  end
end
```

`confirm_and_login_user(user)` is defined in a request_spec_helper which is included as a module in `rails_helper.rb`:

```
# spec/support/request_spec_helper.rb

module RequestSpecHelper
  def json
    JSON.parse(response.body)
  end

  def confirm_and_login_user(user)
    get '/users/confirm', params: {token: user.confirmation_token}
    post '/users/login', params: {email: user.email, password: 'password'}
    return json['auth_token']
  end
end
```

I'm using the jwt gem for generating my tokens as described in this SitePoint tutorial (https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-to-using-jwt-in-rails/)

Comment: Mmm.... getting undefined method `confirm_and_login_user'  error. Do I need to change rails helper config?

Comment: Are you including `request_spec_helper` in `rails-helper.rb`?

Comment: To import the problem, I resolved adding `require 'api_helper'` on the "require" part and, inside on `RSpec.configure do |config|` I put `config.include ApiHelper`

Answer (score 4):

Lorem's answer mostly worked for me.  I got `unrecognized keyword` setting `headers:` on the `get`.  I modified the `authenticated_header` method and put it in `support/api_helper.rb` so I could reuse it.  The modification is to merge the auth token into `request.headers`.

```
# spec/support/api_helper.rb
module ApiHelper
  def authenticated_header(request, user)
    token = Knock::AuthToken.new(payload: { sub: user.id }).token
    request.headers.merge!('Authorization': "Bearer #{token}")
  end
end
```

In each spec file testing the api, I include api_helper.rb.  And I call authenticated_header just before the get statement when testing the case of valid authentication...

```
# spec/controllers/api/v2/search_controller_spec.rb
RSpec.describe API::V2::SearchController, type: :controller do
  include ApiHelper
...
describe '#search_by_id' do
  context 'with an unauthenticated user' do
    it 'returns unauthorized' do
      get :search_by_id, params: { "id" : "123" }
      expect(response).to be_unauthorized
    end
  end

  context 'with an authenticated user' do
    let(:user) { create(:user) }

    it 'renders json listing resource with id' do
      expected_result = { id: 123, title: 'Resource 123' }
      authenticated_header(request, user)
      get :search_by_id, params: { "id" : "123" }
      expect(response).to be_successful
      expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to eq expected_result
    end
  end
```

The key lines in this second test are...

```
authenticated_header(request, user)
get :search_by_id, params: { "id" : "123" }
```